# Copying one directory into another Mac Catalina

Tags: catalina

I have two directories:

```
~/old
~/new
```

Each has subdirectories. What I would like to do, is copy old into new, and overwrite everything. When I do:

```
cp -r ~/new ~/old
```

It creates:

```
~/old/new
```

I tried different things, such as:

```
cp -r ~/new/*/* ~/old/*.*
cp -r ~/new/*/* ~/old
```

~/old and ~/new have very similar subfolders structure, and mostly the same file names, but I want it all overwritten. Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn’t you remove new first if you want to overwrite it? Perhaps your example needs some detail what you want to remain in new and what from old should clobber things in new if you done want new to be wiped.

Comment: new started out as old, but now I want to copy everything from new to old, and I want the existing files to be overwritten. I read the manual, and thought that -r should work, but it did not. Using -R works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do it.

`cp -R ~/old/ ~/new/`

Note that this command copies everything in the *old* directory into the *new* directory overwriting anything that already exists in the *new* directory as you state in your OP.

P.S. See the comments below about why the use of `-R` is recommended instead of `-r` while both may work the same in your case.

Comment: It’s a capital `-R` flag for recursive

Comment: @Allan I think `-r` and `-R` work the same for `cp`.

Comment: Check the man page

Comment: OK, there is a note in the man page which says "Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's." The problem the OP owner has faced does not seem to stem from this but I am changing the `-r` option in my answer to `-R` so that s/he does not run into any other potential problems.

Comment: Great answer, I feel the question is really soft so there’s going to be uncertainty in any answer until the OP has clarified their use case. +1

Comment: The important thing in the answer is to have the trailing `/` on `~/old/`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to copy a folder into a folder, without replacing existing content inside its subfolders, you can use the ditto command, which is preinstalled. This allows you to merge similar structured folders **without overwriting entire folder** if the file names inside are different, but folders are the same. With `cp`, the folders would just replace each other.

`ditto -v old_dir new_dir`

More information [here](https://ss64.com/osx/ditto.html)

Comment: My question says "and overwrite everything."

Comment: Great, but your title does not. Even if your title was more specific, I'm answering somebody else's very similar question.